# ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular change to 24hour format

Tags: angular, datepicker

How to convert the calendar into 24h format?

```
<form>
    <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular
        placeholder="Select DateTime"
        inputDatetimeFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm "
        formControlName="activeEndDate"
        name="activeEndDate"
      ></ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular>
    </div>
  </form>
```

```
formGroup: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      activeEndDate: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular-zcwbcr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: #Please post the code or error into your question, not an image. So that users can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this One**

---

```
let ngbDate = this.form.controls['due_date'].value;
    let myDate = new Date(ngbDate.year, ngbDate.month-1, ngbDate.day);
    let formValues = this.form.value;
    formValues['due_date'] = myDate;
    <...>
    http.post(url, formValues);
```

---